# How to find the largest number of a sequence?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to solve a problem where i need to input numbers in a while loop. The loop will stop if user input the number 0. Then the code should give an output of the biggest number.

```
import java.util.*
fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var remainder = 0
    val n = scanner.nextInt()
    while (n != 0) {
        var input = scanner.hasNextInt()
        if (input > remainder) {
            remainder = input
        }
    }
    println(remainder)
}
```

But when i try to run the code i get this error message:

```
Compilation error
main.kt:8:21: error: type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Boolean was expected
        if (input > remainder) {
                    ^
main.kt:9:25: error: type mismatch: inferred type is Boolean but Int was expected
            remainder = input
                        ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because this method `scanner.hasNextInt()` returns a boolean value and you're comparing the boolean value with an integer value.

```
import java.util.*
fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var remainder = 0
    val n = scanner.nextInt()
    while (n != 0) {
        var input = scanner.nextInt()
        if (input > remainder) {
            remainder = input
        }
    }
    println(remainder)
}
```

You should use `scanner.nextInt()` if you're not getting any string or other kind of input.
If you're getting any other kind of input you can use `scanner.hasNextInt()` and then take the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Kotlin's readLine() function to take user input.
The code will be like this:

```kotlin
var answer = 0
while(true) {
    val n = readLine()!!.toInt()
    if(n == 0) break
    answer = maxOf(answer, n)
}
println(answer)
```